# Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

No me deja crear la tabla `usuaris` por culpa del foreign key y no entiendo por qué :(

```
/* TAULA USUARIS */
CREATE TABLE tb_usuaris (
    id_usuari INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    usuari VARCHAR(30),
    id_rang INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_rang) REFERENCES tb_rangs(id_rang)
);

INSERT INTO tb_usuaris VALUES 
(1,'Sergio Muñoz',7),
(2,'Carlos Martinez',6),
(3,'David Cots',4),
(4,'Isaac Perez',1),
(5,'Daniel Rovira',5),
(6,'Joel García',1),
(7,'Alejandro Nieto',2),
(8,'Adría Aranda',2),
(9,'Manuel Alcantara',3),
(10,'Ricardo Diaz',3);

/* TAULA RANGS */
CREATE TABLE tb_rangs(
    id_rang INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rang  VARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO tb_rangs VALUES
(1,"Becari"),
(2,"Programador"),
(3,"Dissenyador"),
(4,"Supervisor de codi"),
(5,"Administrador"),
(6,"Cap de projecte"),
(7,"Administrador");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas llaves foráneas debes crear/llenar primero la tabla de referencia, de lo contrario cuando esto ocurra la tabla `tb_rangs` no existirá aún y saltará el error:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_usuaris ( 
    id_usuari INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    usuari VARCHAR(30), 
    id_rang INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_rang) REFERENCES tb_rangs(id_rang) 
);
```

Si creas/llenas primero a `tb_rangs` el error debería desaparecer:

```
/* TAULA RANGS */ 

CREATE TABLE tb_rangs( 
    id_rang INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    rang VARCHAR(25) 
);

INSERT INTO tb_rangs VALUES 
    (1,"Becari"), 
    (2,"Programador"), 
    (3,"Dissenyador"), 
    (4,"Supervisor de codi"), 
    (5,"Administrador"), 
    (6,"Cap de projecte"), 
    (7,"Administrador");

/* TAULA USUARIS */

CREATE TABLE tb_usuaris ( 
    id_usuari INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    usuari VARCHAR(30), 
    id_rang INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_rang) REFERENCES tb_rangs(id_rang) 
);

INSERT INTO tb_usuaris VALUES 
    (1,'Sergio Muñoz',7), 
    (2,'Carlos Martinez',6), 
    (3,'David Cots',4), 
    (4,'Isaac Perez',1), 
    (5,'Daniel Rovira',5), 
    (6,'Joel García',1), 
    (7,'Alejandro Nieto',2), 
    (8,'Adría Aranda',2), 
    (9,'Manuel Alcantara',3), 
    (10,'Ricardo Diaz',3);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, la verdad es que nunca me había fijado en esto, gracias a ti iré con mucho cuidado a partir de ahora. <3

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado @xxssisback. Saludos.